# Dynamic variable names in C#?

Tags: c#, variable-names

(There's not an actual function where I need this, but I was just wondering.)

Imagine this function where I pass a `bool[,]`. This `bool[,]` is named `grid1` or `grid2`, depending on the situation.

I was wondering if I can do anything like the following:

```
void CheckGrid(bool[,] grid, int number)
{
    for (int x = 0; x <= gridXmax - 1; x++)
    {
        for (int y = 0; y <= gridYmax - 1; y++)
        {
            if(grid + number[x,y]) //this will check against grid1 or grid2, depending on int number
                //logic depends on whether it's grid1 or grid2
        }
    }
}
```

Guessing by the questions for other languages, it probably isn't possible. But you never know :)

It is well possible I'm missing something obvious here - I'm not really experienced.

Comment: Given that `number` is an int, I honestly have no idea what you hope `number[x,y]` would do.

Comment: Could you not make the grid a parameter to the method?

Answer (score 3):

You can create an array of grids, then use the number value to check that.

```
List<bool[,] grids = new List<bool[,]>();
```

then

```
if (grids[number][x,y])...
```

Answer (score 2):

No - an *object* doesn't have a name, only a *variable* has a name. So although you pass a reference to an array, there's no way that the method can know whether you happened to use a variable called `grid1` for the argument or a variable called `grid2`.

Usually when there are questions like this, the answer involves saying that you *can* use reflection to access member variables by name, but it's generally a bad idea to do so - and that using a single variable which is a collection is a better idea. However, in your question it's pretty unclear what you're trying to do anyway... if it *is* trying to determine "the name of the object" then that's definitely infeasible in general.

Comment: My example was indeed bad, I'm trying to think of new example :)

Comment: @SimonVerbeke: Just out of interest, if you can't think of a good example, why is it important to you whether or not it can be achieved? I'd focus on techniques you *actually* want to use :)

Comment: I was just pondering about such a thing. And I asked it before thinking thorougly about it. Now I realise there is indeed no way to use this. Except, maybe what Norla said. But that could also be achieved with a regular loop.

Comment: @JonSkeet if the grids are elements of a user interface, the corresponding class might very well have a `Name` property.  Novice programmers are sometimes confused by the tendency of designer tools to create a variable named `addressGrid` to refer to a control named "AddressGrid".

Answer (score 1):

You'd be better off passing a flag to your function which would allow you to update your logic depending on whether you are dealing with grid1 or grid2.

Answer (score 0):

This kind of thing exists in PHP when you use something like this $$var where $var will hold grid1 and turn into $grid1

The only thing I could suggest was using key / value pairs in a dictionary and concatenating the number to 'grid'

Comment: Luckily you interpreted my example right, because it appears it was a bad example. The dictionary could indeed be a solution :)

Comment: PHP is not a statically typed language, so you can do all sorts of crazy :)

Answer (score 0):

Add a dimension to your array.

```
void CheckGrid(bool[,,] grid, int number)
{
    for (int x = 0; x <= gridXmax - 1; x++)
    {
        for (int y = 0; y <= gridYmax - 1; y++)
        {
            if(grid[number, x,y]) //this will check against grid1 or grid2, depending on int number
                //logic depends on whether it's grid1 or grid2
        }
    }
}
```